# Making csv file from a list

Tags: python, csv, currency

I have to make simple exchange web, using data from bank. Ive downloaded it and stored in data. Here's my code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/C?format=json")

data = response.json()
```

Now the problem is how to take "rates" list from it and make a CSV file based on that list, that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "table": "C",
    "no": "215/C/NBP/2021",
    "tradingDate": "2021-11-04",
    "effectiveDate": "2021-11-05",
    "rates": [
      {
        "currency": "dolar amerykański",
        "code": "USD",
        "bid": 3.9437,
        "ask": 4.0233
      },
      {
        "currency": "dolar australijski",
        "code": "AUD",
        "bid": 2.9158,
        "ask": 2.9748
      },
      {
        "currency": "dolar kanadyjski",
        "code": "CAD",
        "bid": 3.1679,
        "ask": 3.2319
      },
      # more here
    ]
  }
]
```

I have no idea how to make it. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to a CSV file with dict keys as column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970200/writing-to-a-csv-file-with-dict-keys-as-column-names)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/C?format=json")
data = response.json()

keys = data[0]["rates"][0].keys()
with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data[0]["rates"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
import csv

response = requests.get("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/C?format=json")
data = response.json()
if data:
    with open('rates.csv', 'w') as csv_writer:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_writer)
        wr.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Your solution will write JSON response to the file as a single line.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with `pandas`. Just pass `data[0]['rates']` to `pd.DataFrame` and save as csv:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/C?format=json")
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0]['rates'])
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

|  | currency | code | bid | ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | dolar amerykański | USD | 3.9437 | 4.0233 |
| 1 | dolar australijski | AUD | 2.9158 | 2.9748 |
| 2 | dolar kanadyjski | CAD | 3.1679 | 3.2319 |
| 3 | euro | EUR | 4.553 | 4.645 |
| 4 | forint (Węgry) | HUF | 0.012646 | 0.012902 |